# How to replace two for loops (for two dataframes) with something more efficient

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested

I have two dataframes with one shared column. I'm trying to assign four columns from one dataframe to another (where they don't exist yet) based on that column.
This takes about 45 minutes to run. Is there a better way to do this?

```
df_1['a'] = ''
df_1['b'] = ''
df_1['c'] = ''
df_1['d'] = ''


for i in range(len(df_1)):
    for j in range(len(df_2)):
        if df_1.loc[i, 'common_col'] == df_2.loc[j, 'common_col']:
            df_1.loc[i, 'a'] = df_2.loc[j, 'a']
            df_1.loc[i, 'b'] = df_2.loc[j, 'b']
            df_1.loc[i, 'c'] = df_2.loc[j, 'c']
            df_1.loc[i, 'd'] = df_2.loc[j, 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want `.merge` the dataframes together.

If you have `df1`:

```
   c1  c2  common_col
0   1   2           1
1   3   4           2
2   5   6           3
```

and `df2`:

```
   a  b  c  common_col
0  1  2  3           1
1  3  4  5           3
```

then:

```py
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on="common_col", how="left")
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   c1  c2  common_col    a    b    c
0   1   2           1  1.0  2.0  3.0
1   3   4           2  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   5   6           3  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Comment: Will that work if the common column name contains different values on different rows? What is mean is, df_1 has more rows than df_2, and though the column name is the same and the unique values are the same for that column in each dataframe, df_1 does not have the values in common_col in the same order as they appear in df_2, and also the values in df_1 may appear more than once.

Comment: When I tried this, it created two sets of the new columns - one with suffix _x and one with suffix _y. Do you know what's up with that?